# Apache Superset ENABLE_JAVASCRIPT_CONTROLS is true in config.py/superset_config but does not work

Tags: javascript, apache-superset

I have set "ENABLE_JAVASCRIPT_CONTROLS" to true in config.py file and even added ENABLE_JAVASCRIPT_CONTROLS: True in superset_config.py and then restarted Superset Apache. However, it still shows that I can't use javascript and is still grayed out.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you set `ENABLE_JAVASCRIPT_CONTROLS: True` inside of `FEATURE_FLAGS` block in `config.py` file. So it must look like this:

`config.py`:

```py
...

FEATURE_FLAGS = {
    "ENABLE_JAVASCRIPT_CONTROLS": True
}

...
```